# Opposite gender name for "keep" and "kept women"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

When a married man keeps a another unmarried women for sex, she is called a "keep" or "kept women," right? In the same way, a married women may keep an unmarried man to have sex with him. I want to know the exact name for that man.

Comment: You might check to see if *boy toy* works for your situation.

Comment: **woman** is the singular, **women** is the plural.

Answer (score 4):

The corresponding gender counterpart for a man in this relation is simply a "**[kept man](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kept_man)**". The terminology is parallel.

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kept_man):

> A man who is supported financially by a lover.
>
> > 1917, David Graham Phillips, Susan Lenox: Her Fall and Rise, ch. 17:
> >
> > *The kept man—in and out of marriage—is quite a feature of life in our*
> >     *chaste little village.*
> >
> > 1984 Nov. 19, Richard Zoglin, "Video: Small
> >     World," Time:
> >
> > *A strapping Italian hunk, he becomes the rich actress's*
> >     *kept man, uses her money to start himself in business.*

Answer (score 1):

The phrase 'kept woman' was more common in the past when most women were not financially independent; it implies that a wealthy man is supporting his mistress in a home he has provided for her, not just that he is having an extramarital affair. The reverse situation is less likely, but the lover of a wealthy woman could be described as a 'kept man', or, in modern parlance, a 'toy boy'.

Comment: Say that five times fast.

Comment: Where do you hail from, Kate - and are you a youngster or an 'oldster'? In my neck of the woods (NY metropolitan area) we say "boy toy" (Although your version makes more sense) I wonder if it's a regional or  generational difference.

Comment: @Oldbag 'Toyboy' is the usual expression in the UK - try googling it. I think it's regional rather than generational.

Answer (score 0):

The term **"gigolo"** can also refer to a kept man.

While it is mainly used to describe a heterosexual male prostitute,due to the industry differences between male and female prostitution, a male is often "kept" by one (or, a series) of women, with the understanding that he will probably keep other company to supplement his income.